# Why only 1 image out of 2 is correctly read by tesseract?

Tags: image, image-processing

It's my first experience with tesseract, I'm trying to read the digits contained in these tiff images:

http://imageshack.us/g/703/64553021.png/

As you can see they are in the same format and also same width/height. I don't know why tesseract returns the correct output only for the second image ("150") instead for the first one returns a blank output.

Maybe I should modify them to best fit tesseract? How? I can use Imagemagick if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which options and language did you use? I'm not getting the expected result with both images.

Comment: You have to use `tesseract a.tif output nobatch digits`

Comment: aren't you using the language files like `-l ita`?

Answer (score 0):

In the readme they say:
*In the executable, page layout analysis is enabled by default. You may need to turn it off to process small images. No command-line control for this yet. Sorry. See tesseractmain.cpp.*

I think your images are too small, try editing the code (and recompile).

Comment: But why one image is processed and not the other? Maybe '150' is "bigger" than '75', so the latter is considered as noise. I'll try to enlarge them so!

Comment: Tesseract needs character "x height" to be at least 10 pixels, preferably 20 (see [http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ). The height of those numbers is about 10 pixels, so their x size is maybe 6 - they can easilly be removed as noise. You should resize them 2 or 4 times and get decent results, as they are rather easy to ocr.